# Plot 2 xts time series in one plot

Tags: r, plot, xts, quantmod

Hi I thought this would be a simple task, 2hrs later and I am still struggling.
I was able with this code

```
chartSeries(snp.obj, TA=c("addTA(over,layout=NULL)"))
```

However it comes with a 2 paned plot but I am looking for these two xts objects overlayed with different y-axis to be in one plot not like I have it in the chartSeries plot.

Answer that works but possibly not so elegant:

```
over = xts(over, order.by=snp.obj[121:1730])
plot(snp.obj, main='Shiller PE Timer')
lines(2000*over+1, col= 'red')`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `on=` argument to `addTA` (see `?addTA`)

```
chartSeries(snp.obj, TA=c("addTA(over, on=1)"))
```